# Cloud SQL Access denied

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

```
import webapp2
import MySQLdb
import os

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
        os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/fluent-outlet-604:test-db' , db='guestbook', user='root',passwd='root')
        # connect to the cloud SQL
    else:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='173.194.248.221', port=3306, db='guestbook', user='root',passwd='root')

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT guestName, content, entryID FROM entries')

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.close()
    self.response.write(data)

    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
         ('/',MainPage),
    ],debug=True)
```

when i deploy this app to the app engine i gain error says
"(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify the root password (even if you have set), when connecting from AppEngine.

Remove the **passwd** param from line 9 of your code so that it looks like:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/fluent-outlet-604:test-db' , db='guestbook', user='root')
```

The example code in [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_complete_python_example) also shows this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and solved it.
This problem is on Google Cloud SQL.

In the prompt console, re-start Cloud SQL like below,

`gcloud sql instances --project [app engine project name] restart [sql instance name]`

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem when I didn't specify the hostname in the database URI:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
            'mysql+pymysql://<user-name>:<password>@/<database-name>'
            '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<connection_name>'
```

Changing it to the following fixed it:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
            'mysql+pymysql://<user-name>:<password>@<host-name>/<database-name>'
            '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}'
```